# Having columns with subscripts/indices in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say that I have som data from a file where some columns are "of the same kind", only of different subscripts of some mathematical variable, say `x`:

```
n   A   B   C   x[0]  x[1]  x[2]
0   1   2   3    4     5     6
1   2   3   4    5     6     7
```

Is there some way I can load this into a pandas dataframe `df` and somehow treat the three `x`-columns as an indexable, array-like entity (I'm new to pandas)? I believe it would be convenient, because I could do operations on the data-series contained in x such as `sum(df.x)`.

Kind regards.

**EDIT:**

Admittedly, my original post was not clear enough. I'm not just interested in getting the sum of three columns. That was just an example. I'm looking for a generally applicable abstraction that I hope is built into pandas.

I'd like to have multiple columns accessible through (sub-)indices of one entity, e.g. `df.x[0]`, such that I (or any other user of the data) can do whichever operation he/she wants (sum/max/min/avg/standard deviation, you name it). You can consider the x's as an ensamble of time-dependent measurements if you like.

Kind regards.

Comment: and when you do sum what is the expected output? Is it 15 and 18?

Comment: It should be consistent with how columns in a dataframe already can be added. The result is a new data series obtained by row-wise addition. Thence, sum(df.x) should have 15 and 18 as the first and second rows, respectively.

Comment: Using a pandas.multiIndex for the column names may be an option.

Comment: @Joooeey: This looks promising. I have to look into it to see if it can do what I want (or you can post an example in an answer if you feel like it).

Comment: Why you want to address the columns by `df.x[i]`? Given `x[i]` an arbitrary value in an arbitrary long index vector you could easily access all the columns by `df[x[i]]` or any `df[x[m:n]]`. Which benefit gives you the `df.x[i]` writing? Edit: Of course the index vector `x` has to contain what the column names of `df` are (at least a subset).

Answer (score 3):

Consider, you define your dataframe like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 
                   [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'x0', 'x1', 'x2'])
```

Then with

```
x = ['x0', 'x1', 'x2']
```

You use the following notation allowing a quite general definition of `x`

```
>>> df[x].sum(axis=1)
0    15
1    18
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Interesting take with the indexing. It's not quite what I want though. Is there anny way to get something like df.x[0] accessible like the colum x0?

Comment: Yes, with the example above `df[x[0]]` is the same as `df['x0']`.

Answer (score 2):

Look of column which starts with 'x' and perform operations you need

```
column_num=[col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('x')]
df[column_num].sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: This doesn't quit capture what I'm trying to do. For example, I may not know beforehand how many x's there are (although it should be a reasonably small number). If I were to do something like this I would have to read all the keys, and parse them to find the highest index of any given key. Then I could do the sum up to that index. However, I'm looking for something more abstract, were I can not only find the sum in one single case, but actually treat x as a list/array on which I can do functional operations. sum() is only an example.

Comment: Nice solution for the specific problem in my example (granted, +1), but I'm interested in something more of an abstraction. Do you know if it's possible to do, say, `df.x[0]`?

Comment: yes you can access a column `df['x[0'] ` or `df.x[0]`

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you another answer which will defer from you initial data structure in exchange for addressing the values of the dataframe by `df.x[0]` etc.

Consider you have defined your dataframe like this

```
>>> dv = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=20), 
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([range(4), range(5)]), columns=['x'])
>>> dv
     x
0 0  8
  1  3
  2  4
  3  6
  4  1
1 0  8
  1  9
  2  1
  3  8
  4  8
[...]
```

Then you can exactly do this

```
dv.x[1]
0    8
1    9
2    1
3    8
4    8
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

which is your desired notation. Requires some changes to your initial set-up but will give you exactly what you want.

Comment: I'll fiddle a bit with this one and see how well it plays with other things.